# Problems Proving Injectivity and Surjectivity

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I have these two functions, in which I have to prove or disprove they are injective and surjective:

1. $f:[0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$.
2. $h:\mathrm R \to \mathrm R$ by $h(x,y) = xy$

For the first, I have that it is surjective, as an arbitrary element y in $(0,\infty)$, x = $\frac{1}{y} - 1$, and $\frac{1}{y} - 1$ is in $[0,\infty)$ for any y in $(0,\infty)$. It is also injective as we assume $f(a)$ = $f(b)$, so $\frac{1}{a+1} = \frac{1}{b+1}$ for a,b, in $[0,\infty)$. This means that b+1=a+1 $\to$ b+1-a-1=0 $\to$ b-a=0 $\to$ b=a, so it is injective.

For the second, I have a feeling that it is onto, but I'm not sure how to prove it. Could I say that since x and y are in $\mathrm R$, it follows that xy is in $\mathrm R$ as well? For injectivity, I have that it is not injective, as we can take an example h(2,2) = 4 = h(4,1), but h(2,2) does not equal h(4,1).

Is this valid work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is not surjective. For a function $f: A \to B$ to be surjective means that for every $y \in B$, there is some $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = y$. So, for example, try solving $f(x) = 2$. What happens? Is $x \in [0, \infty)$? Is is, however, injective. To see this, we put
$$f(x) = f(y) \iff \frac{1}{x+1} = \frac{1}{y+1} \iff x+1 = y+1 \iff x = y.$$

As for $g$, it is surjective. Take $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we can make $h(x,y) = c$ by taking $x = c$ and $y = 1$. A function $f$ is injective if $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$. You showed that $h(2,2) = h(4,1)$, but $(2,2) \neq (4,1)$, so it is not injective.

Comment: In the example of 2, we get -$\frac{1}{2}$, if I did my math right, which is not in the domain. I see what I did wrong.

But for h, you say that it is injective in the beginning, and then say it isn't at the end. Did you mean to say it is onto?

Comment: Right. In fact, for any $c>1$, the solution of $f(x) = c$ is $x = \frac{1-c}{c}$, which is a negative number and therefore not in the domain. And yes, I meant to say that $g$ is surjective, but it is not injective. I have corrected that in my answer